# Pandas add one new row to each group

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to add a row for each group in a large dataframe. I want the new row in TIME-column to show the next month and the VALUE column to copy the latest value. In the example below the new row for GROUP A would be TIME='2003-31' and VALUE=4500.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': ['2020-12-31','2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', '2020-12-31','2021-01-31', '2021-02-28'],
              'GROUP':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
             'VALUE':[3000, 4000, 4500, 5000, 5400, 5600]})

data['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIME'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with add month month by [`offsets.MonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html) and then join to original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
data['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIME'])
 
#if necessary
#data = data.sort_values(['GROUP','TIME'])
df = data.drop_duplicates('GROUP', keep='last').copy()
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1) 

data = pd.concat([data, df]).sort_index(kind='mergesort')
print (data)
        TIME GROUP  VALUE
0 2020-12-31     A   3000
1 2021-01-31     A   4000
2 2021-02-28     A   4500
2 2021-03-31     A   4500
3 2020-12-31     B   5000
4 2021-01-31     B   5400
5 2021-02-28     B   5600
5 2021-03-31     B   5600
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for group in data.GROUP.unique():
time = data[data['GROUP'] == group]['TIME'].iloc[-1]
if time[5:7] == '12':
    newYear = int(time[0:4]) + 1
    time = str(newYear) + '-01-31'
else:
    newMonth = str(int(time[5:7]) + 1)
    if len(newMonth) == 1:
        newMonth='0' + newMonth
    time=time[0:5] + newMonth + '-31'
data=data.append({'TIME': time, 'GROUP': group,
                 'VALUE': data[data['GROUP'] == group]['VALUE'].iloc[-1]}, ignore_index=True)
data = data.sort_values(['GROUP','TIME'], ignore_index=True)
```

This code iterates for every unique value in groups and takes their last entrance, updates date and copies last value.